# Will object get collected in that case?

Tags: java, weak-references

Let's say I have a reference tree that looks like that:

```
root => WeakHashMap<View, Binder> => Binder => View
// by WeakHashMap I mean keys (Views) are referenced by WeakReferences
// View is only referenced by Binder
```

Will `View` (and `Binder`) get collected? Or does reference from `Binder` to `View` also has to be weak?

That's how it looks in code:

```
class SomeClass {
    private static final Map<View, Binder> binders = new WeakIdentityHashMap<>();
    // (...)
}

class Binder {
    private final View target;

    public Binder(View target) {
        this.target = target
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: It would be considerably easier to understand this question if you gave an actual example, rather than just describing it.

Comment: Any strong reference to an object will keep it alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html

> Implementation note: The value objects in a WeakHashMap are held by
>   ordinary strong references. Thus care should be taken to ensure that
>   value objects do not strongly refer to their own keys, either directly
>   or indirectly, since that will prevent the keys from being discarded.
>   Note that a value object may refer indirectly to its key via the
>   WeakHashMap itself; that is, a value object may strongly refer to some
>   other key object whose associated value object, in turn, strongly
>   refers to the key of the first value object. If the values in the map
>   do not rely on the map holding strong references to them, one way to
>   deal with this is to wrap values themselves within WeakReferences
>   before inserting, as in: m.put(key, new WeakReference(value)), and
>   then unwrapping upon each get.

As for WeakReference from value to key:

Yes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability

> An object is weakly reachable if it is neither strongly nor softly
>   reachable but can be reached by traversing a weak reference. When the
>   weak references to a weakly-reachable object are cleared, the object
>   becomes eligible for finalization.

Comment: Will `WeakReference` to key in `Binder` allow it to be collected?